# Do I need to rescale input labels before training (label values between 20..51)?

Tags: deep-learning, mse, r-squared

I'm trying to build model for this datatset ([Age prediction](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mariafrenti/age-prediction)):

- The input image has the shape: `3, 128, 128` and the predicted labels (ages) range between 20 to 51.

I want to build model and train it with `MSE` and `R2` metrics.

I built the following model:

```
def GetPretrainedModel():
    oModel = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
    
    for mParam in oModel.parameters():
        if False == isinstance(mParam, nn.BatchNorm2d):
            mParam.requires_grad = False
        
    
    dIn       = oModel.fc.in_features
    oModel.fc = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(dIn, 512), nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(512, 256), nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(256, 128), nn.ReLU(),       
        nn.Linear(128, 1)
    )
    
    return oModel
```

- In order to train the model, Is it worth updating the input true age values to values between 0 to 30 or between 0 to 1 ?
- Is there a recommendation to add another layer to the model which will change the output values to the range between [20..50] ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to scale the "**age**" label as your last linear neuron (in the last layer) is also learning a bias (*b*) parameter.

[image]

Concerning your last point, it could make sense to force your prediction to lay in range [20, 50] **if and only if** you are sure that all your future observations would also be in the range [20, 50] (which is pretty rare in practice, take a look on *data drift* and *concept drift* notions).

If you are sure there will ne drift in your future observations, your idea makes sense. And the best thing to do will be not to add a last layer, but to add a post-processing function to force your prediction to be in that range.